# Postgres: using flag --no-security-labels for loading data into db

Tags: postgresql

I have sql-extension db-file and I need to load it using the **--no-security-labels** flag.

I usually load data from file with the command:

`psql -U postgres -d db_test < db_test_dump.sql`

If I try

`psql -U postgres -d db_test --no-security-labels < db_test_dump.sql`

then I get an error:
*psql: unrecognized option `--no-security-labels'*

I also tried like this:

`pg_restore -d db_test -U postgres --no-security-labels db_test_dump.sql`

but that doesn't work either:
*pg_restore: error: input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql*

How to upload data to db from .sql file with flag **--no-security-labels**?

Answer (score 0):

What is "sql-extension db-file"?  And how does that relate to the rest of your question?

That option is only available on pg_dump and pg_restore.  You can redo the dump with that flag, or redo the dump in custom format (or one of the other formats supported by pg_restore) and then supply that flag to pg_restore.  But either way, you need to redo the dump.  If you don't have access to the original database, perhaps you can set up a scratch database, load the dump to it, and dump from there with the correct option or in the correct format.

Or you could manually edit the existing dump file to remove the security label bits.